# floatingactionbutton.extended display issues flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When the keyboard appears the fab is placed in the middle of the screen instead of staying on board the keyboard

There is a lot of post on this subject on the web, but I cannot find the adequate solution to mine.

Here is the code.

```dart
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
               final isKeyboard = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
               return Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,

//******************************  EDITBUTTON  ***************************** */
                                        
                    elevation: 0,
                   actions: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await Databahelper.instance.deleteNote(widget.note!.id!);
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const StickyNote()));
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete)),
            //***************************     DELETE_BUTTON     ***************************** */
          ],
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              TextField(
                maxLines: 1,
                controller: titleController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  label: Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  controller: descController,
                  maxLines: null,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    hintText: "Enter Your Text...",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                      color: Colors.purple,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
//---------------------------bottomNavigation --------------------------------------
     
            bottomNavigationBar: Visibility(
          visible: !isKeyboard,
          child: BottomAppBar(
            elevation: 4,
            color: backgroundColor,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add_box_outlined)),
                  const Text('July 2050'),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              title = titleController.text;
              description = descController.text;
            });
            NotedB notelocal = NotedB(title: title, description: description);
            addNote(notelocal);
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const StickyNote()));
          },
          label: const Text('Save note'),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.note_add_outlined),
        ));
        }
```

screenshot
[image: floatingActionButton.extend]

Comment: So you want the button to hide inside the keyboard or overlap on the keyboard?

Comment: overlap on the keyboard

Comment: the problem was the expanded widget which was placed around my texfield